# Function Pointers and Memory Management in C

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

Here is the program I have a question about:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int * function1(int);
int * function2(int);

int main(void)
{
    int * result1,* result2;
    int val = 1000;
    result1 = function1(val);
    fprintf(stderr,"result1 = %d\n", *result1);
    result2 = function2(val);
    fprintf(stderr,"result2 = %d\n", *result2);
    fprintf(stderr,"result1 = %d\n", *result1);
}

int * function1(int val)
{
    int result = val + 1500;
    return &result;
}

int * function2(int val)
{
    int result = val - 1500;
    return &result;
}
```

So `result1` is initially set to 2500, and `result2` is -500. However the code did not touch `result1` after initializing it, but it changes from `2500` to something else.  Could anyone give me any hints as to why this happens?

Comment: There are no function pointers in your code. Perhaps you meant functions that return pointers? (A function pointer is, well, a pointer to a function.)

Comment: And why do these functions return pointers at all? Why not simply `result` directly? In that case, there are no problems at all.

Comment: Curious, why post "changes from 2500 to something else" rather than "changes from 2500 to X"?  X is the value you saw.

Answer (score 3):

The content of `result` will no longer available after returning from the function because local variables are allocated on the stack (and are "popped" after function returns).

---

Try by allocating memory dynamically using malloc/calloc:

```
int * function1(int val)
{
    int *result = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *result = val + 1500;
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`result` is an automatic local variable in both of your function. It will no longer exist once function terminates. Returning pointer to an automatic local variable is invalid.
Compiler should raise a warning:

```
[Warning] function returns address of local variable [enabled by default]
```

One possible solution is that you can declare `result` as

```
static int result;
```

and then you can return pointer to it.

---

**NOTE:** There is no function pointer in your code.

Comment: Yes, that is, the variable `result` only exists in local scope

Comment: Why the need for pointers anyway? It is much easier to return result directly: `int function1(int);` and `return result;`.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis; ask this question to OP. I just pointed out the error and suggested a possible solution.

Comment: Certain "Returning the pointer to an automatic local variable invokes undefined behavior."?  Might it instead be the subsequent dereferencing of that pointer which is the UB?

Answer (score 2):

The result variable is only available in local scope.

what you can do is this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int * function1(int);
int * function2(int);

int main(void)
{
    int * result1,* result2;
    int val = 1000;
    result1 = function1(val);
    fprintf(stderr,"result1 = %d\n", *result1);
    result2 = function2(val);
    fprintf(stderr,"result2 = %d\n", *result2);
    fprintf(stderr,"result1 = %d\n", *result1);
    free(result2);
    free(result1);
}

int * function1(int val)
{
    int *result = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *result = val + 1500;
    return result;
}

int * function2(int val)
{
    int *result = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *result = val - 1500;
    return result;
}
```

So, in this way, you will always have the results in your variables.

Answer (score 2):

`result` variable has a block scope in `function1` and `function2`.
So after execution of the `function1`  or `function2`, `result` variable no longer exists.